# Handling HTTP HEAD request using jetty and nginx

Tags: http, nginx, jetty, servlet-filters

I'm looking for the best way to handle HEAD request using jetty (java servlets) and nginx. For my initial "mvp" solution, I was planning on just writing a servlet filter that changes the HEAD to a GET, records the content length, and discards the response. I was also looking for a way to do this purely in nginx, but I wasn't able to find anything on this. It seems like this is a problem that must have been solved before, but I don't see any simple solutions documented on the interwebs. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

Create your servlet so that it extends [HttpServlet](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServlet.html)

Then override the [doHead(HttpServletRequest, HttpServletResponse)](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServlet.html#doHead%28javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest,%20javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse%29) method to handle the HEAD requests.

Comment: Thanks for the response, but I'm looking for something that does not require any new code in my application. I'd like to be able to use the code that I've written for my GETs to handle the HEAD.